# Nginx - how to access Client Certificate's Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, x509, client-certificates

I have an Nginx server which clients make requests to with a Client certificate containing a specific CN and SAN. I want to be able to extract the CN (Common Name) and SAN (Subject Alternative Names) fields of that client cert.

rough example config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/client.crt;
ssl_verify_client on; #400 if request without valid cert

location / {
    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;

}
location /auth_test {
    # do something with the CN and SAN.
    # tried these embedded vars so far, to no avail
    return 200 "
    $ssl_client_s_dn 
    $ssl_server_name
    $ssl_client_escaped_cert
    $ssl_client_cert
    $ssl_client_raw_cert";
}
}
```

Using the embedded variables exposed as part of the [ngx_http_ssl_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) module I can access the DN (Distinguished Name) and therefore CN etc but I don't seem to be able to get access to the SAN.

Is there some embedded var / other module / general Nginx foo I'm missing? I can access the raw cert, so is it possible to decode that manually and extract it?

I'd really rather do this at the Nginx layer as opposed to passing the cert down to the application layer and doing it there.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it through OpenResty + Lua-OpenSSL and parse the raw certificate to get it.

Refer this: https://github.com/Seb35/nginx-ssl-variables/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md#ssl_client_s_dn_x509

Just like this:

```
local varibleName = string.match(require("openssl").x509.read(ngx.var.ssl_client_raw_cert):issuer():oneline(),"/C=([^/]+)")
```

Comment: While this led me down an interesting path (OpenResty, Lua in Nginx, Lua-OpenSSL), it ultimately didn't work. This just gets the issuer information. I couldn't figure out a way to extract the SANs from the cert. Maybe I missed something? I didn't see anything useful here: https://zhaozg.github.io/lua-openssl/modules/x509.html

Comment: This is reading the CN field out of the subject. It's also reading the issuer (the entity signing the cert) which is probably not what you want. The original question is asking how to read the SAN out of the v3 extensions.

Answer (score 14):

You can extract them with the Nginx-builtin [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html), e.g. for CN:

```
map $ssl_client_s_dn $ssl_client_s_dn_cn {
    default "";
    ~,CN=(?<CN>[^,]+) $CN;
}
```

Comment: Since nginx release 1.11.6, the formatting of $ssl_client_s_dn has changed to use commas instead of slashes. (https://serverfault.com/q/829754). The above version reflects that, but there are quite some examples in the wild with the old format
 ~/CN=(?<CN>[^/]+) $CN; 
You can easily overlook the slash instead of the now correct comma. At least took me quite some time to find my config error.

Comment: This would fail if there's only CN presents.

Comment: @js. where does this goes and sits inside nginx.conf? how can i then pass it to backend server as header?

Comment: This does not fetch the SAN. Above code will only give CN

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a lua expert, but here's what I got working:

```
local openssl = require('openssl')

dnsNames = {}
for k,v in pairs(openssl.x509.read(ngx.var.ssl_client_raw_cert):extensions()) do
    for k1,v1 in pairs(v:info()) do
        if(type(v1)=='table') then
            for k2,v2 in pairs(v1) do
                if(type(v2)=='table') then
                    for k3,v3 in pairs(v2) do
                        if(k3=='dNSName') then
                            table.insert(dnsNames, v3:toprint())
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
ngx.say(table.concat(dnsNames, ':'))
```

Comment: What does this do exactly? :) How does the output look?

Comment: And how does this integrate into nginx.conf?

Comment: This will just find all the DNS entries in the SAN and concatenate them with colons and print them. It's just an example, and you could take the list in `dnsNames` and do whatever you want with it. Here's an example of simple lua: https://blog.cloud66.com/supercharging-nginx-with-lua-part-2/

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to set this up in Docker. The official nginx image does not have Lua support. [This image](https://github.com/fabiocicerchia/nginx-lua) does, but then the `openssl` module is not found... Is this the module? https://github.com/zhaozg/lua-openssl

Comment: Finally got this running on Docker using `FROM openresty/openresty:bionic` and `RUN apt-get install -y libssl-dev` before doing `RUN luarocks install openssl`.

Going trough your function now. The [x509.extension](https://zhaozg.github.io/lua-openssl/modules/x509.extension.html) documentation helps a bit :)

Comment: The `toprint()` method didn't work for me (nginx error), but `data()` did the trick: `v3:data()`. BTW I am looking for `uniformResourceIdentifier` rather than `dNSName` extensions.

Comment: Since the question is specifically asking for how to get the SAN list, this is the only answer that actually gives the answer - and should be the accepted answer, @joeweoj

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, when I try to retrieve "subject DN" by a upstream server.
Someone might find the following advice useful. Thus, there is an access
to such fields as ("subject DN" an so on) - you have to look at [link1](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html). Beside it, I had to through this data into the request header, so I've done it via 'proxy_set_header' ([link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/391554/forward-custom-header-from-nginx-reverse-proxy)). It was possible without any extra Nginx extension (there is not need to rebuild them with --modules, just default modules)

Comment: Like the author said, SAN is not exposed by `ngx_http_ssl_module` by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how an URI value can be extracted from client certificate extensions and then forwarded to the upstream server as a header. This is useful when implementing [WebID over TLS](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/WebID/raw-file/tip/spec/tls-respec.html#certificate-example) authentication, for example.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://upstream;

    set_by_lua_block $webid_uri {
        local openssl = require('openssl')

        webIDs = {}
        for k,v in pairs(openssl.x509.read(ngx.var.ssl_client_raw_cert):extensions()) do
            for k1,v1 in pairs(v:info()) do
                if(type(v1)=='table') then
                    for k2,v2 in pairs(v1) do
                        if(type(v2)=='table') then
                            for k3,v3 in pairs(v2) do
                                if(k3=='uniformResourceIdentifier') then
                                    table.insert(webIDs, v3:data())
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end

        return webIDs[1]
    }

    proxy_set_header X-WebID-URI $webid_uri;
}
```

Let me know if it can be improved.