# mTLS with SAN/CN certificate validation

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am following this instruction - [Nginx - how to access Client Certificate's Subject Alternative Name (SAN) field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50613782/nginx-how-to-access-client-certificates-subject-alternative-name-san-field/56168919) and [Getting Common Name from Distinguished Name of client certificate in NGINX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325548/getting-common-name-from-distinguished-name-of-client-certificate-in-nginx)

Question mark -
Assume the certificate contains this

```
%  openssl x509 -noout -subject -in acme-com.pem
subject=C = Hello, ST = World, L = Acme, O = "Hello, World.", CN = *.example.com
```

With help of  nginx-ingress using `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet`, how do we be able to validate the SAN or CN matching `*.example.com` ? for example We have this below mTLS and want to also ensure that the client certificate should also carry matching SAN or CN. As part of validation, if succeed, move forward otherwise deny.

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: default/ca-cert
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: optional
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "3"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($ssl_client_verify = SUCCESS) {
        set $service_name "default-yes-mtls-backend-80";
      }
.. 
...
```

Is this something  can be done ? Yes - came across this below page mentioning `ssl-client-subject-dn`, can validation check happen on this ?
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#client-certificate-authentication